# Any way for Mongoose to continue save if validation fails for some changes?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

In my schema I've set minimum length requirements for some keys.

```
mphone: {type: String, minlength: 1},
hphone: {type: String, minlength: 1},
wphone: {type: String, minlength: 1},
```

The information for the above is populated through a form that the user submits. When the user submits the form, the following runs to save the information to the DB.

```
 var query = Sample.where({'sample.email' : username});
 query.findOne(function(err, sample) {
    if(err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
    else {
        sample.mphone = req.body.mphone;
        sample.hphone = req.body.hphone;
        sample.wphone = req.body.wphone;

        sample.save(function(err) {
            if(err) console.error(err);
        });
    }
```

However, if the user only fills out one of the fields in the form and submits it (for instance, fill out only mphone), because of the validation on the schema, the whole save operation is rejected. Is there a setting that would allow Mongoose to simply reject the invalid fields and save, say, only mphone? I guess I could test and save each one individually, but I'd like to know if there is a more efficient way.

Comment: Well then you don't actually want it to have a `minlength` or `required` constraint now do you? If you are in fact asking for "custom validation" where "either" of the fields must have something present, then that would require a "pre" middleware hook, rather than the defined default validators.

Answer (score 0):

Some operations (e.g. create()) will skip validation altogether according to the docs.

That said, if your rule is that at least one of the fields be filled out, then you should use a validation middleware.  Something like this (untested):

```
SampleSchema.pre('validate', function(next){
   if(!this.mphone && !this.hphone && !this.wphone) return next(new ValidationError('At least one type of phone is needed!')); 
   next();
});
```